# How to solve this "Content type detection for rest requests is deprecated" issue of elastisearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash

I'm getting to much logs in my Elasticsearch server and this log takes too much memory on disk. every 2-3 hour,server is getting around 4 GB logs.

Logs looks like-

[2017-05-08T03:08:14,616][WARN ][o.e.d.r.RestController ] Content type detection for rest requests is deprecated. Specify the content type using the [Content-Type] header

Comment: `Specify the content type using the [Content-Type] header` => One the of the clients that is interacting with your ES server is not sending the `Content-Type: application/json` header while it should as ES doesn't auto-detect content anymore.

Comment: is it because of changes in API?

Comment: Which ES version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those using curl, a simple addition of

`-H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Made the trick for me

Answer (score 2):

Updating my clients, in my case elasticsearch-model and elasticsearch-rails resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue by indicate the contentType when creating the HttpEntity:

```
ContentType contentType = ContentType.create("application/json", "UTF-8");
HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString, contentType)
```